# Is "Zamharir" a part of Jahanam?

Tags: islamic-basis, jahannam

I recently came across a concept that one of the punishment in Hell is a very cold place called Zamharir.

But I'm unable to find any supporting Hadiths with a valid sanad.

Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept "**Zamharir**" is found in authentic Hadiths:

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> The Prophet () said, "In very hot weather delay the Zuhr prayer till
> it becomes (a bit) cooler because the severity of heat is from the
> raging of the Hell-fire. The Hell-fire of Hell complained to its Lord
> saying: O Lord! My parts are eating (destroying) one another. So Allah
> allowed it to take two breaths, one in the winter and the other in the
> summer. The breath in the summer is at the time when you feel the
> severest heat and and the severe cold too is due to the zamharīr".
>
> ~ [Bukhari 537](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:536)

> Abu Huraira reported:
> The Messenger of Allah said: The Fire made a complaint before the Lord
> saying." O Lord, some parts of mine have consumed the others." So it
> was allowed to take two exhalations, one exhalation in winter and the
> other exhalation in summer. That is why you find extreme heat (in
> summer) and zamharīr (extreme cold).
>
> ~ [Muslim 617](https://sunnah.com/muslim:617a)